# How to trigger ClickOnce re-install without new version?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, clickonce

So I have a Windows Forms app that uses an encrypted connection string for the database.

Every quarter we change the database password, but the vendor only upgrades this app maybe every 12 or 18 months.  So because of this, the "appname.exe.config.deploy" file that is hosted on the clickonce webserver would have our new password--but the hundreds of desktops would still have the old .config file with the old password because the verision has not changed.

I know I can delete the %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\ folder (deleting potential unrelated click-once apps in the process), but we are talking hundreds of desktops and that's not really feasible here.

I would like to know if/how I can tweak the .manifest or whatever in order to "fake" the clickonce to think it needs to re-install.   I can't imagine I'm the first one with this issue but I've found nothing satisfactory in my searches so far.
Thank you.

Comment: From [what I can see](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsto/2010/03/09/tricks-with-app-config-and-clickonce-deployment-saurabh-bhatia/) the config file should be part of the Manifest for the application - how are you generating a new Manifest that includes you config file? That should cause an application update.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately install\reinstall process initiating when no application installed or version has changed.

I don't understanding, why so important having old one ClickOnce version, because your clients will make update process anyway.

If new copy installation is fine for your clients, then you can set new "Application instance name". Your customers launch will do new instance installation of your application. I'm really don't know how to change this name from Visual Studio or Mage.exe, but you can download my utility from second [download link](http://www.devowl.net/2017/04/Alternative-Mage-UI-Sozdanie-ClickOnce-prilozheniya.html) here. [Choose] your application folder -> [Update] action -> Add any prefix for [Application instance name] field value (for example "_1") -> [Build] + [OK].

Anyway, version increment is the best solution for you.

Comment: Sergey, thanks, but I don't fully understand what you're saying. 
 However it sounds like the utility you propose requires that I have the source code.  This is vendor code and I have zero access to the source so I can't rebuild the click-once without that (that I know of).

Comment: You don't need vendor source code for make ClickOnce application.